# Convert every file from JPEG to GIF in terminal

Tags: command-line, convert

I have work with find before to find all specific files in a folder and subfolder and do something about it

For example, I did use

```
find /folder/ -name '*.txt' -exec chmod 666 {} \;
```

This code to easy change write access to every text file in the folder.

Now I was going to try to convert every jpg(even JPG) to gif in the same way but not sure if that is so easy. When I try with the convert command tools it wants to have an inputfilename and output filename but I do not think find give that so maybe find is not the right Tools to use?

Comment: Do you mean X amounts of jpegs so you get 1 GIF. Or 1 gif for every jpeg?

Comment: Note that your example makes the `*.txt` files world-writable with that mode `666`. That is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Why do you want GIF in this day and age except for animation?

Comment: Note that GIF supports upto 256 colours from a 24-bit palette. JPG supports 24-bit colours. You are likely to introduce dithering artefacts doing this

Comment: Well that is true that is not good idea to make every textfile 666 but when I did use this code I did have to do that to make some script work.

Some file is GIF as default and some was JPG, that I have done now is just use at it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Find can be used for this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161480/85695), but I find it easier to use the shell instead. If your files are all in the same directory (no subdirectories) you can just do:

```
for f in /path/to/dir/*jpg /path/to/dir/*JPG; do
    convert "$f" "${f%.*}.gif"
done
```

The `${var%something}` syntax will remove the shortest match for the glob `something` from the end of the variable `$var`. For example:

```
$ var="foo.bar.baz"
$ echo "$var : ${var%.*}"
foo.bar.baz : foo.bar
```

So here, it is removing the final extension from the filename. Therefore, `"${f%.*}.gif"` is the original file name but with `.gif` instead of `.jpg` or `.JPG`.

If you do need to recurse into subdirectories, you can use bash's `globstar` option (from `man bash`):

```
globstar
    If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion con‐
    text will match all files and zero or  more  directories
    and  subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /,
    only directories and subdirectories match.
```

You can enable it with `shopt -s globstar`:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in /path/to/dir/**/*jpg /path/to/dir/**/*JPG; do
    convert "$f" "${f%.*}.gif"
done
```

Comment: Ahh globstar was something new for me, and it works greate that you give me.

Answer (score 5):

You can indeed use `find` - with a shell wrapper that calls the appropriate `convert` command and generates the output file using paramemter substitution. Ex.

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -execdir sh -c '
  for f; do convert -verbose "$f" "${f%.*}.gif"; done
' find-sh {} +
```

Change `-name` to `-iname` to include the `.JPG` extension (although note that the replacement `.gif` extension will be lower case regardless).

Comment: wow nice, nice to know if I need to change something easy and fast

Comment: Why ask `find` to combine a whole bunch of results into a single commandline, only to split them apart again?

Answer (score 1):

There's another tool in ImageMagick, `mogrify`, that's designed to make batch processing easy. This does what you want:

```
shopt -s globstar
mogrify -format gif **/*.jpg
```